# enable acl in VPS

Tags: vps, access-control-list

How can I enable `acl` in my VPS? I have the next in `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw          0    0
```

And executing `df` I get:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      52428800 1971916  50456884   4% /
none              104860      64    104796   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              524288       0    524288   0% /run/shm
```

When I try to do:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:manolo:rwx app/cache
```

I get "operation not supported" for each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using OpenVZ. In this case you need to open a ticket with the service provider; the community cannot help.

Answer (score -2):

You can issue the command: `mount / -o remount,acl`

Comment: OpenVZ doesn't allow that: "mount: permission denied"